# Bash variable name is result of concatenation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do :

```
declare -a array=(first second third)
for i in ${array[@]}; do
  ${i}_arg=$(some commands here...)
done
```

Expected result:

```
first_arg=something1
second_arg=something2
third_arg=something3
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my issue adding "export" before the variable name. Not sure if it's the best way.

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is an answer, just fine. I would recommend using `declare` instead of `export`, though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I agree with you. +1

Comment: @Bastien974, ...by the way, to explain *why* `declare` is a better choice than `export` here -- it's about side effects. `export` also adds a variable to the process environment, to be inherited by children, whereas `declare` will set it locally to the shell (actually, locally to the current shell function, if inside a function). If you don't need to export something to your children, it's better not to waste memory inside their process space (environment variables count against the same limited storage space as argv contents).

Answer (score 3):

If possible, abandon this approach *per se* and use associative arrays instead. They're available in bash 4.

```
declare -A args
arg[$i]=$(some commands here)
```

Answer (score 3):

First: Unless you have a very compelling reason to use this instead of associative arrays, don't. [The answer given by kojiro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29980219/14122) is more appropriate as a best practice.

Second: This topic is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). To summarize options given there...

---

You can use `typeset` (in bash, ksh, or zsh) or `declare` (in bash):

```
typeset "${i}_arg=$(some commands here...)"
```

---

You can use `printf -v` (in recent bash):

```
printf -v "${i}_arg" %s "$(some commands here...)"
```

---

You can use `read`:

```
IFS= read -r "${i}_arg" < <(some commands here...)
```